# Comparing occurances on two observations on SAS

Tags: sas, radix, enterprise-guide

Hi I have a data treatment problem on SAS. I have transaction history for every customer and  i have also created a Customer_Tranx_Number. In addition to this i have flagged every transaction with a 1/0 occurrence of an event flag.

Now I want to find in which observation does the  event flag changes from 1 to 0 and flag the  event which shows first "0" after "1". Also i have to do this flag creation for every customer separately

How can I code this on SAS?

I tried to illustrate problem on the following link, in advance thank yo very much for all your help.

http://zeybekomer.blogspot.com.tr/2015/10/blog-post_12.html

Regards

Comment: Look at the LAG function, which will give you the value for a previous record. Make sure you check that the customer is the same as the LAGged record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATA NEW;
SET YOURS;
IF LAG1(CUST_ID)=CUST_ID AND LAG1(FLAG_1) != FLAG_1 THEN NEW_FLAG="FLAG=1";
RUN;
```

That code will check to see if the it is the same customer.  Then check if current record flag is equal to the prior record flag for the "FLAG_1" variable.

You can get more specific if needed with specifying additional boolean logic such as when prior value of flag_1 is 1 and current is 0, then define ect....

Comment: by following  your code i created this code                                                      IF LAG(CUST_ID,1)=CUST_ID AND (BALANCE - LAG(BALANCE,1))>0 THEN FLAG="FLAG=1";         but it does state that ERROR 72-185: The LAG function call has too many arguments.

Comment: Sorry, mixed up languages.  Use LAG1(Cust_id)  instead of the syntax I gave you.  Same with balance.